# Can I avoid many spaces in multiple nested loops in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to do numerical calculations with Python. This involves 7 nested loops (I have a 5-dimensional array and need to loop over that).

That is a lot of spaces or indents. I am constantly spending my time moving my editor window from left to right and back, or typing in tabs/spaces.

Is there any way to avoid this?

EDIT:
Here is some Fortran pseudocode for a simplified version of my problem. Hopefully it should show you how I need to customize accessing the 5-dimensional array `fe`'s indices. Note how operations depend on other arrays defined at different index positions and how there are conditional statements that control some of the indices too:

```
do iy=1,ny
do ix=1,nx
do im=0,mmax
imm=im-1
imp=im+1

nqi=ni
if(im.eq.0) nqi=1
do ii=1,nqi
iq=3-2*ii
iiz=3-ii

do in=im,nmax

do ip=1,np
fb(ii,ip,in,im)=0.5d0*( fe(ii,ix,iy,ip-1,in,im)+fe(ii,ix,iy,ip+1,in,im) ) 
enddo
fb(ii,0,in,im)=0.d0 
enddo

fb(ii,0,0,im)=fe(ii,ix,iy,1,0,im)

do ip=0,np
do in=im,nmax

qdp=0.5*Fy(ix+2,iy,ip)

inm=max(0,in-1)
inp=in+1
qfb=fb(ii,ip,in,im)

qfb=qfb-qdp*( Gb(ii,ip,inm,imm)*cGyzm(in,im)  - Gb(ii,ip,inm,imp)*cGyzp(in,im) )

fb(ii,ip,in,im)=qfb
enddo
enddo

enddo
ii=1

enddo
enddo
enddo
```

Comment: you need to show your code !

Comment: You can use an indentation of 2 instead of the standard 4.

Comment: No, you cannot avoid indenting when using a for loop. You can reduce the number of spaces from 4 to something like 1 or 2.

Comment: `import this` -- *"Flat is better than nested."* You should refactor to avoid the loops - [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or `numpy` may help with this.

Comment: If you are doing numerical calculations, then use numpy arrays and let numpy do the looping for you.

Comment: @Rob I can't let numpy do the looping as this is numerical analysis (finite difference) which requires a quite complex relationship between array indices. Numpy as far as I can tell is only useful for basic numerical analysis e.g. involving matrix algebra.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks but it looks like itertools has only a basic set of operations and since I am doing numerical analysis I need to define my own operations.

Comment: @kotozna then perhaps it would be helpful to show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're actually doing, as Kasra has already suggested.

Comment: @VincentBeltman Could you provide a link as to how to reduce the indentation size?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @VincentBeltman PyCharm, though I'd prefer an IDE-independent solution if there is one.

Comment: If you have an indent like 'ssss' just delete two like 'ss'. And you're done. Only one rule: Keep the same indent over the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably move some of the inner loops into their own functions, this would reduce indentation and make your code easier to understand as well.

Comment: why the downvote? this is exactly what you should do when you have lots of nested loops

Comment: I didn't want to do this as each loop has many dependencies on quantities calculated in previous loops and this would require passing lots of arguments back and forth.

Comment: And yet, it is highly recommended. Especially because it makes it easier to refactor your code. I'm sure that if you actually showed the python code, you'd get lots of suggestions for improvement/refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have your array `A` of dimension 5, and lists of indices to go through for each dimension.
You can flatten that with use of `itertools.product` and tuple unpacking:

```
indices = itertools.product(ind_1, ind_2, ind_3, ind_4, ind_5)
for x, y, z, j, k in indices:
   elt = A[x][y][z][j][k]
   # do something with elt :)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will enable me the complex control I need over loop indices that I need at each level of the loop. I have added code to my original post.